# How to create graph for Boston Dataset in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, graphics

My data is "Boston Housing Dataset", I want to produce a graphic that looks like this:[image]

the code for the plot is in Python (unfortunately, I do not know python only r). link for the Code: kaggle.com/prasadperera/the-boston-housing-dataset .
but instead of y='medv' i need y='crim' with all the rest of the variable, in order to find predictors that have an interesting association with the crime.
 I have tried to do this in r, my code is:[image]

Very appreciative of the help, Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Perhaps you can describe where exactly you are getting stuck. It's easier to help you if you show the code you've started with so far.

Comment: Please edit the question and add this code snippet to it, rather than posting it in the comments. @litaldayan

Comment: l have edit my question @nilāmbara Thank!

Comment: l have edit my question Thank! @MrFlick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do something similar in ggplot is with faceting. Here's what that might look like

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data(Boston, package="MASS")

Boston %>% 
  select(crim, lstat, indus, nox, ptratio, rm, tax, dis, age) %>% 
  gather(obs, val, -crim) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(val, crim, color=obs, fill=obs)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=TRUE) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~obs, scales="free_x") +
  scale_color_discrete(guide=FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)
```

The basic key is to reshape the data so you can draw just one plot and facet it rather than drawing many plots and arranging them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it helped me a lot :) @MrFlick